# How to design a database for financial bond prices?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have following flat file table composed of bond deal names and asociated prices.

Each deal name is identified by its unique CUSIP and ISIN codes and each deal name is classified with a certain deal type.

One deal name can have many prices over the course of a day.  Each price is classified with a different price type; as in the following table:

*field names are shown in brackets like (XXX).*

- CSAMF 2A PREF (name) 12629B309 (cusip) 3,000,000 (size) M50S (original price) 55.00 (price) TALK  (price_type) CLO (deal_type)  23/09/2012 (date)
- CSAMF 2X PREF (name) KYG2577W2005 (isin) 2,000,000 (size) M50S (orig_price) 55.00 (price) TALK  (price_type) CLO (deal_type) 23/09/2012 (date)
- FN 465343 (name) 31381M5C5 (cusip) 2,613,100 (size) 80a (origin_price) 80a (cmbs_spread) 80.00 (cmbs_price) TALK (price_type) CMBS (deal_type) 24/09/2012 (date)
- FN 465273 (name) 31381M2E4 (cusip) 1,760,000 (size) MH70s (origin_price) MH70s (Cmbs-spead) 77.00 (cmbs_money)TALK (price_type) CMBS (deal_type) 24/09/2012 (date)

Each deal name has either one CUSIP or one ISIN or both.  Prices with deal type of CMBS (Commercial Mortgage Backed Securities) are recorded from the original price into CMBS spread and prices with deal type other than CMBS are converted into money prices.

I have constructed two possible solutions for the relational database, as shown below:

**Design 1:**

```
Deals (deal_ID, name, CU_code, IS_code, deal_type)

Price (price_id, orginal_price, money, cmbs, cmbs_money)

Deal_price (deal_id, price_id, date, size, price_type)
```

---

**Design 2:**

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[deal_2](
[cusip] [varchar](100) NULL,
[isin] [varchar](100) NULL,
[name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[deal_type] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
 ON [PRIMARY]

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[price_2](
[price_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[cusip] [varchar](9) NULL,
[isin] [varchar](12) NULL,
[orig_price] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[price] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[cmbs_spread] [varchar](50) NULL,
[cmbs_price] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[size] [int] NOT NULL,
[price_type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[date] [date] NOT NULL
ON [PRIMARY]
```

[image]

---

Is it possible to construct a relational database design for this domain?

Which DDF would be appropriate for this domain?

Comment: I have implemented design 2 approach and I am trying to run the following query: **SELECT d.name, d.cusip, d.isin, p.orig_price, p.price, p.cmbs_spread, p.cmbs_price, p.size, p.price_type, d.deal_type, p.date
FROM dbo.price_2 p
INNER JOIN dbo.deal_2 d
ON d.cusip = p.cusip
ORDER BY p.date**.  The problem I am having is that I have 109 instances in the database (sqlServer) but the query is outputting 11339 instances and I am not sure why? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How many records do you have in `price_2`?  The syntax of your query is fine, the results you're getting is because that is how many combinations there are of `deal_2.cusip` and `price_2.cusip`.  There must be a lot of repetition in the cusip values in each table.

Comment: @Joel Brown, Thank you so much for your response. I have 109 records in Price_2 and Deals_2 tables. The cusip column has the following data type: (cusip VARCHAR(9) NULL). I am assuming the duplication is caused due to the null data types in the dataset. How can I resolve such problem, that I get 109 records instead of 11339? Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Have you tried taking nulls out of the equation by adding a clause like `WHERE p.cusip IS NOT NULL AND d.cusip IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Dear @Joel Brown, I had tried using the Where clause before which resulted in no data output. The cusip column has 36 null entries in the both of the tables. Apology for not mentioning that in my earlier post. I am not sure, how to make this query work. Thank you for your time and help. Much appreciated.

Comment: It is unlikely that your NULLs are causing the issue.  Instead, I think you must have some repetition in your non-null cusip values.  Have a look at this SQL Fiddle query.  You'll see that the null FKs don't join: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4961b/1/0

Comment: Dear @Joel Brown, There were duplications in deal_2 table and I managed to remove those. Table price_2, will have duplicates as it corresponds to many to many relationship with the deal-2 table, as one deal can have many prices and vice versa. I managed to get the query to work by editing my dataset. Thank you so much for the above link and I really appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly an answer... but... my 2cents (not interest bearing, might interest ing).

So, Security X has identifier (ISIN or CUSIP).
This identifier doesn't identify the trade, exchange, currency - just the security.

This Security has value, established by trades - which fluctuates over time, place...
This is tracked by deals. A deal requires a Security.

Price is parcel of deal.

I would create a table of Securities - Security (it has an ID int identity(1,1) PK), Code Unique constraint, CodeType (CUSIN/ISIN), linksToID (here is a funny: ISIN can have CUSIP too so link both to each other so you can identify the securities by either code)
etc.

I would create a table of Deals - Deal (it has an ID int identity(1,1) PK), time, place, and Security.ID, and TYPE).

I would create a table of Prices - Trade (it has an ID int identity (1,1) PK, DealID, Value, currency, TIME, etc)

So, I would create a unique/distinct list of securities, and insert that into Security.
Matching the Security to TradeReport (assuming the trade report to be the data you want to capture contains either ISIN or CUSIP but not neither) insert the ID of the matching ISIN of the trade data, and then inserting the matching ID of the CUSIP matching if a linked item isn't already there! to get a unique deal list.

Then I would reference the different deals back to the same import data and capture the prices of the deals to the prices table.

See the hierarchy?

from there you can splice and dice your analysis...

Yeah, that about covers my thinking... hope it helped.